# How to bypass "File in use" prompt when opening an Excel file (when in use by someone else) from a SharePoint URL?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I'm working on a vba-excel project that lets multiple users upload data programmatically to a specific (***EDIT: password protected***) file located in our company's SharePoint. The issue is that when multiple users start an upload at the exact same time (which is not very likely, but possible), the upload procedure runs only for one user, and the rest are prompted with the following message:

[image: file in use prompt]

Since the file to be updated must be open with read/write permissions the macro will not be able to perform the upload.

---

I've been unsuccessfully trying to find a code that could bypass this message, so the macro could handle it programmatically.

One approach I tried was to check if the file is currently in use, before opening it:

[***myFile*** is a string containing the location of the main file to be updated (SharePoint URL)]

The code below basically opens/closes 'myFile' in the background, and checks if any error was raised while trying to open it. Then it returns True/False if the file is in use or not:

```
On Error Resume Next
Open myFile For Binary Access Read Lock Read As #1
Close #1
fileInUse = IIf(Err.Number > 0, True, False)
On Error GoTo 0
```

It works as it should, but **not** when using URLs.
The result when using a traditional DOS path, is an error number of 70 when the file is in use, and 0 if not.
The result when using a URL path is always 75.

---

The code below is supposedly able to perform the check on SharePoint URLs, but for some reason it's not working for me:

```
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(myFile) = True Then
    'Open file
Else
    'Run procedure to wait a few seconds and then try again
End If
```

It always returns True, disregarding if the file is currently in use or not.

---

***The expected result is:***

If myFile is currently in use:

  Wait a few seconds and try again.

If it's not:

  Continue with uploading procedure.

myfile will only be accessed programmatically, so the only times when it will not be available is when other user is currently running the upload procedure somewhere else, and this will take around 5 seconds.

---

Any suggestions or comments are very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to open the file as read only?

Comment: If you are opening the workbook using code, use `Workbooks.Add` instead of `Workbooks.Open`

Comment: @alowflyingpig @braX thanks for your suggestions. The file will be updated, so it must have **write** permission, so `Workbooks.Add` is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting [`Application.DisplayAlerts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts) to `False` to suppress the popup. Then check [`Workbook.ReadOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts) to see if the file opened as read-only. If it did, you can close it and then try again in a few seconds. Just make sure to set `DisplatAlerts` back to `True` when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried turning off display alerts, but the **File in use** prompt still shows up (I just edited my question to add the fact that the file is password protected. I'm not sure if that affects this specific approach).

Answer (score 0):

Code taken from microsoft hlp that I use... Will determine if the fil is open. If open will return `TRUE`

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub FileOpen()

        Dim MasterFile as string
        MasterFile = "your file location"    

        Dim Ret
        Ret = IsFileOpen(MasterFile)

        If Ret = True Then
            MsgBox "File is currently in use."
        Else
            MsgBox "File not in use."
        End If


    End Sub

    ' This function checks to see if a file is open or not. If the file is
    ' already open, it returns True. If the file is not open, it returns
    ' False. Otherwise, a run-time error occurs because there is
    ' some other problem accessing the file.

    Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
        Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

        On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
        filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
        ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
        Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
        Close filenum          ' Close the file.
        errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
        On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

        ' Check to see which error occurred.
        Select Case errnum

            ' No error occurred.
            ' File is NOT already open by another user.
            Case 0
             IsFileOpen = False

            ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
            ' File is already opened by another user.
            Case 70
                IsFileOpen = True

            ' Add in as many other cases' as you'd like
            Case 75                    
                IsFileOpen = True

            ' Another error occurred.
            Case Else
                Error errnum
        End Select

    End Function
```

Comment: This is exactly where my first attempt came from. As I mentioned, it works but not for SharePoint URLs as the file address. `errnum` will always be `75` when using a URL, disregarding if the file is in use or not.

Comment: The code above was modified to support `errnum 75` The code should work as needed..